# When I play a live stream youtube video in VLC the resolution drops?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, streaming, youtube

When i am playing any regular video in VLC from youtube the quality remains the same. But when I put in a url for a livestream youtube link the quality drop down to to 480p. Is there a way to maintain the quality?

I am eventually trying to extract frames from the live sream video on youtube. Is there another approach I should consider.